# Hibernate - Mapping table to Entity class does not work: QuerySyntaxException: Class is not mapped

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I checked the numerous threads about this but no solutions are working. According to those threads, the mapping should work.

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Product is not
>   mapped [from Product]

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        ...
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <mapping class="api.test.model.Product" />
    </session-factory>
 </hibernate-configuration>
```

Product.java:

```
 package api.test.model;
 import java.io.Serializable;
 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.Table;

 @Entity
 @Table(name="products")
 public class Product implements Serializable{
 ...
 }
```

Dao:

```
 public List<Product> getProduct(Integer id) {
     List<Product> products = (List<Product>) openCurrentSessionwithTransaction()
     .createQuery("from Product").setMaxResults(100).list();

     return products;
 }
```

This does not throw error but no results possible:

```
 .createQuery("from " + Product.class.getName()).setMaxResults(100).list();
```

I also tried mapping the class in persistence.xml, doesn't work either:

```
 <persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
    <class>api.test.model.Product</class>
```

[Full stacktrace as requested](http://pastebin.com/uQ6RfZKe)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Product in the right package? Your example of Product.java does not have package api.test.model;

Comment: Thanks, but yes, it's in the correct package..

Comment: please share your complete exception stacktrace

Comment: @Ahmed Nawaz [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/uQ6RfZKe)